# Demonstrate that c exists

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, continuity

If $h$ is an application $h : [0,3] \to \mathbb{R}$ continuous in  $[0,3]$ and derivable in $(0,3)$ with $h(0) = 1$, $h(1) = h(3) = 2$. Demonstrate that $c$ exists with $c \in (0, 3)$ with $h'(c) = 1/3$.

I've tried proving that $h'$ anulates in $(0,3)$ to apply the Darboux theorem. But I don't really know how to demonstrate it.

Comment: Ever heard of the mean value theorem?

Comment: yees I know what. it is

Comment: but how can I use it??

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

To clarify the initial comment, your problem can be solved by a direct application of the Mean Value Theorem, which states the following:
Let f(x) be differentiable on the open interval $(a,b)$ and continuous on the closed interval $[a,b]$. Then there is at least one point $c$ in $(a,b)$ such that $f'(c)=\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{(b-a)}$

We can interpret this as saying that the derivative must take on the average slope over an interval at some point $c$ in that interval. In the x-interval $[0,3], h$  varies from $1$ to $2$: in other words, the slope is $\frac {2-1}{3-0}=\frac{1}3$, meaning $h'(c)=\frac{1}3$ within that interval by the MVT.